# Buy Bitcoin in the UK

Tags: buy-bitcoins

Where can I buy Bitcoin in the UK? Preferably at Gox prices? I have tried at bitcoin.info and on Gox. I'd prefer not to go through a local sale.

Thanks

Comment: [This question has been asked a lot before.](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=bitcoin+uk+is%3Aquestion)

Answer (score 0):

The other GBP market which is available is based on www.bitcoin-central.net

They are based in France, the liquidity is not of that of MtGox but for casual buy orders this should not be much of a problem.

Most other options involve individual trades and no exchange as such exists within this country anymore.